# AWS WorkMail Create User API throwing `OrganizationNotFoundException` error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-workmail

So I was using boto3 to connect with AWS WorkMail. I used one of my IAM User and gave the full WoekMail Permission to that user. I have an organization created and I wanted to programatically create an user for it using one of their [API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workmail.html#WorkMail.Client.create_user).

So my code looks something like this:

```
import boto3

from config import aws_credentials

client = boto3.client('workmail', **aws_credentials)

response = client.create_user(
    OrganizationId="m-69a01**********************848eb",
    Name='abhi',
    DisplayName='abhi jain',
    Password='********'
)
```

So I keep getting this error:

`botocore.errorfactory.OrganizationNotFoundException: An error occurred (OrganizationNotFoundException) when calling the CreateUser operation: Could not find organization with id 'm-69a01**********************848eb'`

Just to make sure I double-checked my Organisation ID and have attached a screenshot. I am not sure if this is the right Organisation ID to be used with this API.

[image: AWS Organization Settings Screenshot, I have whitened my creds. But you can still see the start and end of OrganizationID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my mistake, the aws credentials was set to the `us-west-2` region while my organization was present in `us-east-1`.

So as I cannot change my Organization region, I changed my region in my `~/.aws/config` to the same region as my organization and used the same code and it worked like a charm.

```
import boto3

from config import aws_credentials

client = boto3.client('workmail', **aws_credentials)

response = client.create_user(
    OrganizationId="m-69a01**********************848eb",
    Name='abhi',
    DisplayName='abhi jain',
    Password='********'
)
```